# JSF 2.0 and Primefaces with Facelets

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I'm trying to incorporate primefaces into my JSF 2.0 web project.

I've recently updated from facelets 1.x to 2.0 and Added primefaces jar to my library folder. Everything is fine except, the way I have my templates structured has a conflict with the primefaces.

my ***template.xhtml*** looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <title><ui:insert name="title">MILO</ui:insert></title>

    //Css   
    //js        

</h:head>

<h:body class="milo">
    <h:form styleClass="miloForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="container">
                <ui:insert name="header">
                    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/header.xhtml"/>
                </ui:insert>

              <ui:insert name="content">
                    <!--  include your content file or uncomment the include below and create content.xhtml in this directory -->
              </ui:insert>

              <ui:insert name="footer">
                <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/footer.xhtml"/>
              </ui:insert>          </div>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

And my ***index.xhtml*** *looked* like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/base.xhtml">

<ui:define name="content">

         <p:editor/>        
</ui:define>
```

Once I have this, the p:editor won't show up. any ideas why? the console won't show me any warnings/errors.

EDIT>>>  Found JS Error

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `template.xhtml`, you need to **replace** `<head>` by `<h:head>` and `<body>` by `<h:body>`. You shouldn't add another ones, that would only result in invalid HTML.

Particularly the `<h:head>` is mandatory as it allows component libraries like PrimeFaces to auto-include the necessary CSS/JS files by resource dependency injection. The `<h:body>` is only mandatory whenever you have `<h:outputScript>` elements with a `target="body"` so that they will be auto-relocated to the very bottom of the generated HTML `<body>` element.

---

**Update** your concrete problem is caused by a conflict in the manually loaded jQuery library and the one which is auto-included by PrimeFaces. PrimeFaces uses jQuery and jQuery UI under the covers. If you stick to using PrimeFaces, I'd recommend to drop the manually loaded jQuery and use the PrimeFaces-bundled one instead. To cover pages where you don't use PrimeFaces components as well, you can explicitly load PrimeFaces-bundled jQuery for every page by adding the following line to the `<h:head>`:

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
```

Comment: I updated my question to reflect my findings. changing the < head> to < h:head> and < body> to < h: body> doesn't if it, the error I get is gone, but the p:editor won't show up anymore. why do you think that is?

Comment: Not sure since your code contains way too much noise (you should learn how to create and provide an SSCCE), but your master template has already a `<h:form>` and yet you've put another one in the template client around `<p:editor>`. Nesting forms is invalid in HTML.

Comment: I'm sorry. :( I'll see if I can trim all the unecessary parts. I understand your point.

Comment: I trimmed all the fat, now all I have is lean code. does this help? =)

Comment: Okay. Rightclick page in browser and do *View Source*. Do you see `<p:editor>` still unparsed in there? Or do you see its generated HTML? If you see its generated HTML, please check if you see any JS/CSS files in the generated `<head>` with a `?ln=primefaces` in URL. If so, please check webbrowser toolset (press F12 in Firebug/Chrome/IE9) if you see any errors in JS console.

Comment: the HTML is parsed out, and the < head> has 5 instances of ln=primefaces. so I uploaded the error it gives me ( used IE)

Comment: if I remove <script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/jquery.js"></script> from my template and <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){ $(".button").button(); }); </script> Then it works... Do you think the js is having some conflicts?

Comment: Yes, PrimeFaces ships with jQuery bundled. I'll update the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9758/discussion-between-myy-and-balusc)