# How to make method return null with redirect

Tags: java, redirect, jsf-2

in jsf i want to go back to the same page but with redirect. so if the user click refresh i don't want the form to be submitted again.

```
public String changeLanguage() {
    if (locale == Locale.ENGLISH)
        locale = new Locale("ar");
    else
        locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
    return null;
}
```

view code :-
mybean sessionscope

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:m="http://medicalgate.com/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>#{msg.hello}</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view locale="#{mybean.locale}">
        <h:form>
            <h:commandLink value="lang" action="#{mybean.changeLanguage}"></h:commandLink>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: What problem do you have with the current code that just performs a page forward and keeps you at the same page?

Comment: this code return me to the same page, and when using browser refresh button this method is called again and i don't want that.

Comment: It shouldn't, can you post your view code?

Comment: done view code added.

Comment: That doesn't call the method when page refreshing. Which JSF version/impl are you using?

Comment: jsf 2.2 impl in glassfish 3.1.2 i think it's majora

Comment: You must have something more in your view that is issuing your code. The example you provided works form me with that version.

Comment: that's the full page code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer to this is not as simple as it would seem at a glance. JSF is a framework heavily based on being stateful, and the P-R-G pattern you are wanting does not play nicely with it.

If you absolutely MUST do this, then you will need to make your bean request scoped and use view parameters to persist state.

Essentially, you'll need to make the following changes:

---

MyBean.java

```
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {
    public string submit() {
        String outcome = "MyView?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true";
        return outcome;
    }
/* Bean goes here */
}
```

---

MyView.jsf

```xhtml
<html>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="fname" value="#{myBean.firstName}"/>
    </f:metadata>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText value="#{myBean.firstName}"/>
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{myBean.submit}"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

---

Unfortunately this comes with a downside, and that is your parameters will be put into GET parameters (`http://mysite/MyView.jsf?fname=test`), but your pages won't have issues with postbacks either.

So, the tradeoff is your decision to make, statefulness to break the back button, or statelessness and extra work fighting the stateful nature of JSF to avoid postbacks.

Comment: Just pointing out that you can do away with the repetitive arguments with a navigation handler as described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5416070/785663

Comment: Of course you can use a custom NavigationHandler to clean it up, OCPSoft's Rewrite library makes it a lot cleaner since you can just annotate your fields with @Paramater("name") and eschew the entire viewParam mess. I was trying to give an example that just used vanilla JSF to be safe :)

Comment: You're not sending any view param never in your code, even you're taking it from your view. That doesn't keep the state of `#{myBean.firstName}` field.

Comment: @XtremeBiker That's precisely what the includeViewParams=true bit of the redirect does. All view parameters of the current page are automatically added to the redirect when this parameter is included in the outcome.

Comment: Ok, haven't seen that, I eat humble pie! Anyway and regarding your example just note you're missing `h:head` tag, which [is higly recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10037641/1199132).

Comment: @XtremeBiker The example is missing a lot of things, the goal was to show enough to demonstrate usage and concepts, not give something that could be copy/pasted verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). You'll see how the page title is set according to the current locale. When you click on the link, the method is invoked once and it's not called again even you refresh the page. Note your `mybean` is replaced by `myBean`:

```xhtml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<f:view locale="#{myBean.locale}" encoding="UTF-8"
    contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>#{myBean.locale}</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Selected locale: #{myBean.locale}
        <h:form>
            <h:commandLink value="lang" action="#{myBean.changeLanguage}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

```java
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean {

    Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;

    public String changeLanguage() {
        System.out.println("Method called");
        if (locale == Locale.ENGLISH)
            locale = new Locale("ar");
        else
            locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
        return null;
    }

    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

}
```

Comment: still no way it's not working for me. i am using primefaces api in my project. could it be the reason ?