# The Prime Faces out put is not ideal out put

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i want to use prime faces to create a panel  and my `.xhtml` is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:body>
<p:panelGrid columns="2">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Basic PanelGrid
    </f:facet>

    <h:outputLabel for="firstname" value="Firstname: *"/>
    <p:inputText id="firstname" value="" label="Firstname"/>

    <h:outputLabel for="surname" value="Surname: *"/>
    <p:inputText id="surname" value="" required="true" label="Surname"/>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton type="button" value="Save" icon="ui-icon-check" style="margin:0"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:panelGrid>
</h:body>

</html>
```

the result is :

[image]

but the desired output is :

[image]

what this problem caused and how can i resolve it?

Comment: What theme are you using ?

Comment: i use `glass-x` theme that i declare it in `web.xml`

Comment: have you added the required jar or maven dependancy for this theme?

Comment: i just add `primefaces-3.4.1.jar` and `primefaces-3.4.1-sources.jar` lib to use prime faces

Comment: I guess that you need to add `<h:head></h:head>` before the `<h:body>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF 2.0 and Primefaces with Facelets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036928/jsf-2-0-and-primefaces-with-facelets)

Comment: it shows too big , how can i control it , please post your comment as answer so i can accept it

Comment: Define `style="width:50%"` in the `<p:panelGrid>`. Looks like you need to review some HTML + CSS development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to `themes` work you'll need to add that to your project. Since you're using normal `project(non maven)`. Download the `all-themes` jars from [here](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/all-themes/1.0.10/all-themes-1.0.10.jar)

Add that jar to your build path and try running again.

Comment: reset the theme and try

Comment: you mean to delete it and add it again?

Comment: It's not a theme problem, but OP forgot to add `<h:head>`.